# Will Development on my Android Phone Cause Problems?

Tags: android

I would like to start looking at development for Android applications (nothing huge, just for learning). Before I begin, I would like to find out whether or not development on the Android phone I use daily would be corrupted or changed in some way if I used it as a development device.

I probably won't put anything on the Market, but I would just like to test out how everything "works" with Android development.

Any help that will guide me is great.

Thanks.

Comment: No problem at all, apps install and uninstall very clean and easy on Android. If your apps don't work, uninstall them and that's it. Nothing damaged or altered. I use my personal phone for dev purposes on a daily basis, no problems yet *(except that the hardware back button starts to die, but that would also happen with normal usage after some time)*.

Comment: I've had to reboot my device a few times after rather heavy debug/crash sessions but beyond that there's been no issues at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not at all! Sorry for the shortness of the answer, but that's it.

The only problem I can think of is writing to internal memory more than usual, but if you install a lot of new apps, the effect will be the same, so it's nothing special. And as alextsc said, if you write something and it doesn't work, just remove it, and that's all.

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't cause any problems at all. The only problem I can imagine is that you have to enable installation of applications from unknown sources (i.e. not the marketplace). You just need to be sensible not to go installing applications from dodgy places.

Answer (score 3):

Not at all. But even better, when you [set everything up](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) (Eclipse, the Android SDK and the ADT Eclipse plugin) you'll also get an Android emulator that you can test your development projects on virtually.

Still, it's just fine (and recommended) to do testing on an actual device, but if you're just playing around, you can likely just use the emulator and only deploy to your device if the end result is something you'd like to show off to your friends!

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you! (I must go with the first response for the answer; it's only fair)

Answer (score 2):

Hey in addition to the above answers,

You should actually test on your device when you are making an app that uses one of the following :

1. GPS, or wi-fi to get user location
2. when you want to use any phone sensor in your app
3. when you are trying to integrate camera/ camcorder in your app
4. also you might need to actually test phone call/sms functionality integrated in an app

otherwise the emulator just works fine